# Duplicate query in webi

Tags: webi

How to duplicate a query in webi, in query panel if the query is not duplicated then what is the reason and how to resolve this issue suggestions please

Thanks in advance
Shoaib

Comment: You have to run a query (refreshing is not enough) before you can duplicate it. What are you trying that is not working?

Comment: Unable to duplicate the query through query panel in webi report through BI launch pad . When we right click the query and try to click the duplicate option, nothing happens, but it is happening in webi rich client tool kindly suggest is this is some kind of server/access issue.

Comment: Which option do you have selected from in the Web Intelligence section of you BI Launchpad Preferences? We have all users set up with "HTML" for both **View** and **Modify**. Switch to "HTML" if you don't already have that.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have "HTML" selected under both **View** and **Modify** within your BI Launchpad Preferences...

[image]

like this...

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help Isaac, i will try this one for sure....

Comment: I have tried your method but still I can't duplicate query in webi, can you suggest any other method?

Comment: I am not aware of any other options. Do you have any level of product support? If you do, I would recommend contacting them.